# Ao clicar na DIV limpar textbox

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Tenho umas DIV que abrem um modal, porém gostaria de que quando clicasse, limpasse o textbox, aqui é onde tenho a DIV que ao clicar abre o modal:

```html
 <div class="link-box">
                <a href="#dialog" name="modal" class="linkmodal" runat="server" id="modalExercutar">Cadastro de agenda avaliação física</a>
            </div>
```

Tentei fazer uma função em JS porém não deu certo.

Queria também limpar somente a seleção do gridview. Ex: clico para selecionar uma linha, ao clicar no linkmodal, não deixar nenhuma linha selecionada.

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" DataKeyNames="id" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" PageIndex="10" SelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" TabIndex="10" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1" PageSize="1000000">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="data" HeaderText="Data" SortExpression="data" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HtmlEncode="False" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="hora" HeaderText="Hora" SortExpression="hora" HtmlEncode="False" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="avaliador" HeaderText="Avaliador" SortExpression="avaliador" HtmlEncode="False" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Aluno" HeaderText="Aluno" SortExpression="Aluno" HtmlEncode="False" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="razao_social" HeaderText="Empresa" SortExpression="razao-social" HtmlEncode="False" />
                        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Select" Text="<img src='images/icon/Misc-Edit-icon.png' title='Editar'/>" />
                        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" DeleteText="<img src='images/icon/Trash-can-icon.png' title='Excluir' />" />
                    </Columns>
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com JS ficaria da seguinte forma:

```js
jQuery(function($){
   $('.linkmodal').click(function(){
        $('#txtid').val('');          
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="link-box">
       <a href="#dialog" name="modal" class="linkmodal" runat="server" id="modalExercutar">Cadastro de agenda avaliação física</a>
</div>
<br><br>

Textbox <input type="text" id="txtid" value="teste">
```

Com relação à `grid` tente o seguinte script:

```js
jQuery(function($){
   $('.linkmodal').click(function(){
        $("#GridView1").empty();          
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="link-box">
    <a href="#dialog" name="modal" class="linkmodal" runat="server" id="modalExercutar">Cadastro de agenda avaliação física</a>
</div>

<br><br>

<div id="GridView1" style="border:1px solid; height: 40px;">
conteúdo
</div>
```

Fiz com uma `div` utilizando o mesmo id da `grid` para ilustrar, já que aqui não dá para testar o código da `grid`, observe que ao clicar a `div` permanece, mas o conteúdo é apagado.

Comment: Fiz desse jeito que informou Leandro, porém não funciona. Apenas troquei o textbox pelo txtid que é o ID no meu textbox.

Comment: @marianac_costa Tente novamente, editei o post colocando exatamente o id informado. Lembrando que você tem que colocar a chamada do script (jquery.min.js) dentro da tag head da página.

Comment: Funcionou certinho Leandro, obrigado. Você sabe como faço para limpar seleção do grid na função? Queria junto com essa. Obrigado.

Comment: @marianac_costa Edita o post principal e posta o trecho do código da grid para eu visualizar como está a grid em questão e editar a resposta com a função para limpar a grid também.

Comment: Editei .. do jeito que estou fazendo, ele desaparece o grid, gostaria que só limpasse a seleção. Obrigado.

Comment: @marianac_costa Editei o post colocando um script para limpar o conteúdo sem remover a grid, fiz com uma div para ilustrar o comportamento do script.

Comment: Desta forma ele está removendo o Grid.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60447/discussion-between-leandro-silva-and-marianac-costa).